# live555 streaming using ByteStreamMemoryBufferSource

Tags: live-streaming, live555

I plan to make rtsp server and clients using live555.

get data from clients, and send the data to other species of clients.
like replicator.

RTSP servers(Other) ----------- RTSPClients(My Program) - data in memory - RTSPServer(My Program) ----------- RTSPClients(Other)

like this.

but there is no sample using ByteStreamMemoryBuffer. Only there is ByteStreamFileSource.

is there any reference or sample???
thanks.

Comment: If you don't make particular processing the [LIVE555 Proxy Server](http://www.live555.com/proxyServer/) is doing the job.

Comment: i should make particular process of it...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I decided to change proxyserver codes.
it is much more easier than using memorybuffersource.